# Java Thread.sleep for minimum time

Tags: java, thread-sleep

The [TimeUnit.sleep(long timeout)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep-long-) documentation describes its argument thus:

> timeout - the minimum time to sleep.

However, I'm finding that — at least on Windows 7 64-bit with Java 8 update 141 — the thread often sleeps for *less* than the minimum:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final long from = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(100);
    final long to   = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1000);
    final long step = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(100);
    for (long requestedSleepDuration = from; requestedSleepDuration < to; requestedSleepDuration += step) {
        long sleepStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(requestedSleepDuration);
        long sleepEndTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf(
                "requested=%9d  actual=%9d  %s%n",
                requestedSleepDuration,
                sleepEndTime - sleepStartTime,
                (sleepEndTime - sleepStartTime >= requestedSleepDuration ? "OK" : " Slept less than minimum!"));
    }
}
```

Typical output:

```
requested=100000000  actual= 99534864  Slept less than minimum!
requested=200000000  actual=200063646  OK
requested=300000000  actual=299223086  Slept less than minimum!
requested=400000000  actual=399598620  Slept less than minimum!
requested=500000000  actual=499910360  Slept less than minimum!
requested=600000000  actual=600028523  OK
requested=700000000  actual=699604816  Slept less than minimum!
requested=800000000  actual=799230602  Slept less than minimum!
requested=900000000  actual=899490648  Slept less than minimum!
```

This seems to contradict the documentation. However, the TimeUnit doc also states that `TimeUnit.sleep()` is a convenience wrapper for `Thread.sleep`, and the latter doesn't say if it guarantees to sleep at least the specified amount.

Is this an API implementation error, or is `TimeUnit.sleep` and/or `Thread.sleep` designed to only sleep for *approximately*, rather than *at least*, the specified duration?

Comment: I always thought they were approximate, not guaranteed

Comment: The system clock typically has a resolution of 15ms. Why are you trying to sleep in nanoseconds?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not trying to sleep in nanoseconds, and I'm not trying to be exact, but would like to sleep for *at least* the required time. A little more is ok. I'm only using nanoseconds because Java's monotonic clock is `System.nanoTime()` - there's no alternative unit. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is unsuitable as it's subject to clock adjustments.

Comment: Man. I typed out a reasonably long answer and now I can't post it. Can someone vote to reopen?

Comment: @Michael my apologies, I marked the question suggested in the duplicate notice as "This answers my question" and that marked my question as a duplicate. I now can't undo it. I voted to reopen, but this requires 4 votes. 2 so far, 2 more needed to reopen. I don't like the way SO works.

Comment: Yep, it's rubbish. I just posted a similar (though slightly different) question [and answered it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420662/how-can-i-guarantee-that-thread-sleep-sleeps-for-at-least-a-minimum-amount-of-ti/) in case you're interested.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou SO questions aren't like forum discussion threads. You don't reopen an answered question to ask a different follow-up question, you just post it as a new question, so people with that specific question can find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TimeUnit.sleep()` delegates to `Thread.sleep()`.

`Thread.sleep()` is subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers, thus `TimeUnit.sleep()` will not be as accurate as you may need.

Comment: Thanks. So when the TimeUnit javadoc says "timeout - the minimum time to sleep", it's lying.