# How can I guarantee that Thread.sleep sleeps for at least that amount of time?

Tags: java, sleep

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45419940/1898563), `Thread.sleep` is not necessarily guaranteed to sleep for the duration you specify: it may be shorter *or* longer.

If you read the documentation for [`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-), you'll see there are no strong guarantees over the exact duration which will be slept. It specifically states the duration is

> subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers

which is (intentionally) vague but hints that the duration should not be relied upon too heavily.

The granularity of possible sleep durations on a particular operating system is determined by the thread scheduler's interrupt period.

> In Windows, the scheduler's interrupt period is normally around 10 or
>   15 milliseconds (which I believe is dictated by the processor), **but a
>   higher period can be requested in software and the Hotspot JVM does so
>   when it deems necessary**

[Source](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml), emphasis mine

How can I practically guarantee that the sleep duration will be at least the value that I specify?

Comment: What is your use case for making the thread sleep x time? Are you just scheduling? If so there are better ways to do this

Comment: @UserF40 one application I had in mind is throttling requests (or other types of event) to say, a maximum of N events per second. If you are about to make the Nth request and the 1st request was made less than a second ago, you need to wait *at least* the required amount of time before you make the request.

Comment: @UserF40 I don't personally have a use case (if you look at the comments of the linked question you'll see why I asked this ;) ) but what Klitos mentioned seems reasonable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best practical solution is to time the sleep and continue to sleep while there is time remaining:

```
public void sleepAtLeast(long millis) throws InterruptedException
{
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long millisLeft = millis;
    while (millisLeft > 0) {
       Thread.sleep(millisLeft);
       long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
       millisLeft = millis - (t1 - t0);
    }
}
```

Code and info is from [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep_issues.shtml)

Comment: Good solution but I would advise against using `currentTimeMillis`. If the user adjusts the system time (or you use an NTP service) while your Java application is running, this method will behave incorrectly. Use `System.nanoTime()` instead.